# accessing kdb+/q table via python in Json?

Tags: python, python-requests, kdb

I am trying to access kdb+/q table via python. I know there are some libraries that help communications between python & q, but I wanted to see if it is possible to do so without using above libraries as there are some constraints on kdb+ version.

My initial guess was:

1. define table in kdb+q; access kdb via python using urllib- 
   urllib.request.get("localhost:5000?.j.k TABLE_NAME") but it wasn't successful.
2. Another approach I had was using pd.read_csv("localhost:5000/q.csv?select from table ...") but this approach couldn't work out due to HTTP 406 error.

What are the flexible/easy way of retrieving kdb table from python? Any advise/guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[PyQ](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/pyq/install/) is possibly the most commonly used and best supported approach. You say you have version constraints but PyQ has been around for a long time and I'm sure you could download versions which are compatible with older versions of kdb.

If not, some other options are:

https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython

https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/embedpy/

and a few options documented here: http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api

Across all of these I'm sure you'll find something that works

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use both methods you suggested with success

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://localhost:35207/.json?enlist trades")
>>> r.json()
[{'time': '2019-02-07D08:00:53.319000000', 'sym': 'ORCL', 'src': 'N', 'price': 32.23, 'size': 1099}, {'time': '2019-02-07D08:01:26.649000000', 'sym': 'YHOO', 'src': 'O', 'price': 35.52, 'size': 471}, {'time': '2019-02-07D08:01:36.413000000', 'sym': 'YHOO', 'src': 'L', 'price': 35.52, 'size': 438}]
>>>
```

The `enlist` is required as per note at https://code.kx.com/q/ref/doth/#htx-filetypes

Note that `.json` is used here, similar to `.csv` in your example CSV query; kdb will automatically encode response as JSON when a query like this is sent.

Note: This will work on versions of kdb 3.3+ (JSON support was added in 3.2, querying over HTTP was added in 3.3). To use similar on older versions, you can download [json.k](https://code.kx.com/svn/kx/kdb+/e/json.k) from kx & do the following:

```
q)\l json.k //from kx, not needed for 3.2
q).h.ty[`jsn]:"application/json"
q).h.tx[`jsn]:.j.j'
```

And then modify the HTTP query to `r = requests.get("http://localhost:35207/.jsn?enlist trades")` -> not the extension `.jsn`, which is a hack here to avoid modifying `.z.ph`, the HTTP request handler. [I tested this on v2.8]

Alternatively, using CSV & Pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv("http://localhost:35207/.csv?trades")
                            time   sym src  price  size
0  2019-02-07D08:00:53.319000000  ORCL   N  32.23  1099
1  2019-02-07D08:01:26.649000000  YHOO   O  35.52   471
2  2019-02-07D08:01:36.413000000  YHOO   L  35.52   438
```

If you are still experiencing issues with these methods, please post detailed error outputs to assist with debugging.

As others have observed, it is likely going to be much more straightforward using one of the available q-python libraries, but I think if that isn't possible, it should be doable over HTTP requests as above.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to use already available api for Python-Q integration as mentioned by @Terrylynch. That will simplify lot of operations and will be more efficient as well for most of the cases.

But if you want to do this totally in Python using http requests, then you could use 'requests' module:

```
import requests as req
res=req.get("http://localhost:5000/?.j.j t")
res.text
```

Sample Output

```
'<html><head><style>a{text-decoration:none}a:link{color:024C7E}a:visited{color:024C7E}a:active{color:958600}body{font:10pt verdana;text-align:justify}</style></head><body>
<pre>"[{\\"id\\":1,\\"v\\":3},\\n {\\"id\\":2,\\"v\\":4}]"\n</pre></body></html>'
```

As you can see, that will give you html text so you need to parse it to get the result from the required tag. There are couple of python modules available for html parsing, so you could use those.